# ASP.NET Text to Speech Code working on local dev machine but not on production server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a ASP.NET application that does text to speech TTS. The code works fine on local machine but when I deploy it on windows 2008 R2 server Enterprise 64 bit, the application pool just crashes. The application is made of v4.0 .NET framework. I am using IIS 7 on server. Below is the error when application pool crashes.

```
Service Unavailable

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

Here is the code which should I added ealier

```
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        context.Response.ContentType = "audio/wav";

        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            ss.SetOutputToWaveStream(ms);
            ss.Speak(context.Request.QueryString["tts"]);
        });
        t.Start();

        t.Join();
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
        context.Response.End();
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Here is more details of Exception

```
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/17/ROOT

Process ID: 5340

Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Message: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A832755E-9C2A-40B4-89B2-3A92EE705852} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

StackTrace:    at System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.VoiceSynthesis.Speak(Prompt prompt)
   at System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.Speak(Prompt prompt)
   at TTS.<>c__DisplayClass3.<ProcessRequest>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I have given full permission to IIS_USRS to file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Speech SDK 5.1\Bin\TTSEng.dll. Now the error has changed to

```
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/17/ROOT

Process ID: 2816

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException

Message: No voice installed on the system or none available with the current security setting.

StackTrace:    at System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.VoiceSynthesis.Speak(Prompt prompt)
   at System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.Speak(Prompt prompt)
   at TTS.<>c__DisplayClass3.<ProcessRequest>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

I dont have any sound device on my server. Is this exception correct?

Comment: Check the Application Log in Event Viewer for the error details.

Comment: Here is the error log **Application pool 'DomainName.com(domain)(4.0)(pool)' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.** , **A process serving application pool 'DomainName.com(domain)(4.0)(pool)' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '4948'. The data field contains the error number.**

Comment: There should be additional errors before that entry that tell you what the actual problem is. IIS will shut down application pools that fail a certain number of times in a certain time frame. You can configure this in the app pool settings.

Comment: I have added exception details in the main question. Kindly check and respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

1. Is IIS running
2. Default website running
3. App pool and ASP.Net version
4. Access is appropriate

Comment: ISS and default website running. ASP.NET version in 4 and app pool has .NET version of 4. Yes Access is appropriate as I am able to access other pages of site easily.

Comment: Is text to speech s/w trying to access/write content/file at any particular location (where thread is not having access ? )

Comment: download ProcessExplorer and try to analyze step by step

Comment: also disable antivirus and try again.. sometimes it may block access to some temp/generated files

Comment: the problem was with granting appropriate access. I have set Identity of application pool to "LocalSystem". Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

zahid has the proper answer here.
In IIS, select the Application pool, click advance settings, then select the Identity type.

Speech needs to access data at user level.

Comment: I had the same problem, and it was solved by changing identity to local system on our server. but what is the solution when I'm publishing the application on a public hosting like A2 hosting or godaddy as an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try granting read/write access to `C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\appdata\roaming` for the same user that the app pool is running under.